# Trying to pass in Variable to FirebaseFirestore Where Clause in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the passed in variable into the Where Clause as chapterName being passed in?

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but passed in value does not seem to be available in the manner that I am doing this.  I have tried replacing string with variable.  Not allowing.  I have tried to use many alternatives with no luck.  Only "Text" seems to work.

Apologize I am not experienced developer but trying to get this out to a team to use.

Any suggestions?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:member_shmc_app/screens/home/members/members_admin/admin_member_details.dart';

//New starting point -- need to change to filter by User's Chapter Members ONLY
//Attempt to take HomePage and pass in ChapterName
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MemberListHome extends StatefulWidget {
  MemberListHome({required this.chapterName, super.key});
  var chapterName = '';

  @override
  State<MemberListHome> createState() => _MemberListHomeState();
}

//Works now but need to replace Chapter Name with variable of chapterName
final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> _referenceMemberList = FirebaseFirestore
    .instance
    .collection('shmc_members')
    .where('memberChapter', isEqualTo: 'Gray Ghost');

class _MemberListHomeState extends State<MemberListHome> {
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _streamMemberItems;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamMemberItems = _referenceMemberList.snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("SHMC Chapter Members"),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138),
          foregroundColor: Colors.white),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _streamMemberItems,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> listQueryDocumentSnapshot =
                querySnapshot.docs;

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listQueryDocumentSnapshot.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  QueryDocumentSnapshot document =
                      listQueryDocumentSnapshot[index];
                  return MemberListItem(document: document);
                });
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MemberListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const MemberListItem({
    super.key,
    required this.document,
  });

  final QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> document;

  @override
  State<MemberListItem> createState() => _MemberListItemState();
}

class _MemberListItemState extends State<MemberListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        minLeadingWidth: 10,
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AdminMemberDetails(widget.document.id)));
        },
        title: Text(widget.document['memberRoadname'] +
            ' - ' +
            widget.document['memberChapter']),
        subtitle: Text(widget.document['memberFullName'] +
            " - " +
            widget.document['memberCellPhone']),
        //leading: Image.asset('images/chapters/' + widget.document['chapterLogo']),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you saying that this doesn't work: `.where('memberChapter', isEqualTo: chapterName);`? If not, is there an error?

Comment: It shows up underlined in red -- and then:  

"Undefined name 'chapterName'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."  Only create mixin is option that is offered to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

You're defining `_referenceMemberList` outside of the `_MemberListHomeState` class and that is why you can't access the `chapterName` variable.

### Solution:

Move the `_referenceMemberList` definition into the `_MemberListHomeState` and use the `chapterName` variable in the `_referenceMemberList` as `widget.chapterName`.

See below:

```dart
class _MemberListHomeState extends State<MemberListHome> {

  Query<Map<String, dynamic>> get _referenceMemberList =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('shmc_members')
          .where('memberChapter', isEqualTo: widget.chapterName);

  /// The rest of your code
}
```

### *Note:*

*I converted the `_referenceMemberList` from a class variable to a getter because `widget` (used in `widget.chapterName`) isn't available in initializers i.e when definining `_referenceMemberList` as a class variable.*

Comment: You are awesome Victor -- I had moved it before and tried as well, but did not know about the Note: you left -- converting this to getter actually was the missing piece!!  Thanks!!